# WordPress plugin by using Dart Language

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart, wordpress-plugin-creation

**Can we develop #wordpress plugin by using #Dart and #Flutter?**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**, you can't develop WordPress plugins with dart/flutter, dart can be compiled to javascript on the web, but WordPress require it's plugins to be written with HTML/CSS, JavaScript for the front end, and PHP, SQL for the back end.

Comment: can you guide me about the WordPress plugin development like roadmap...

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/